# How to read the select statement to understand the result

Tags: sql-server, oracle, learning

I am convinced that it is a very basic question, but I still have to ask it, making queries on the Oracle HR schema I notice that the result of these two queries is different:

[image]

Expected result:
[image]

I would like to know why this happens, when using the parentheses it gives me the result I want, while if I do not use the parentheses it gives me another record (Pat Fay) that does not make sense, how should I read this sentence to understand these outputs, thank you very much .

Comment: Because AND has higher [operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) than OR. This concept applies generally to almost all languages - precedence matters.

Comment: This order of precedence doesn't _ONLY_ apply to "almost all languages".  It is a basic, fundamental mathematical concept that one learns on the first day of Algebra I.  In fact, I'd say that if there is a language that does _not_ implement it ("applies generally to _almost_ all languages) then that language is fundamentally flawed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's about order of operations: "and" happens before "or", so

```
where department_id=20 or department_id=50 and salary >= 8000
```

is actually the same as

```
where department_id=20 or ( department_id=50 and salary >= 8000 )
```

and has a different result than

```
where ( department_id=20 or department_id=50 ) and salary >= 8000
```

where the parenthesis force the order of operations to be different and the department ids are evaluated together.